# I have one issue for ViewState

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

What is the meaning of `EnableViewState="false"` and `EnableViewState="true"`?

I Know `EnableViewState="false"` = turn Off the ViewState and also  `EnableViewState="true"` = turn On the ViewState

But What is the difference between `EnableViewState="false"` and `EnableViewState="true"` ?

I tried this code:

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" EnableViewState="true" runat="server">
</asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

I am really confused. 
When I used `EnableViewState="true"`, I entered some values in `textbox` and click my button .Now the value is here in the `textbox` . Its same process when i set `EnableViewState="false"`.

So **What happens when `EnableViewState="true"` and `EnableViewState="false"` ?**

Comment: See: [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx). Or [When is safe to disable viewstate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861537/when-is-safe-to-disable-viewstate?rq=1).

Comment: It's not help me . i want just What is the process in EnableViewState="true", and EnableViewState="false"

Comment: You have read that quite quickly then. What do you mean by "what is the process"? You mean what happens if you disable the ViewState? Nothing, if you don't use controls that rely on the ViewState.

Comment: yea! you are right . Just tell me What happen when EnableViewState="true", and EnableViewState="false" ?

Comment: _"Just tell me"_? I linked to two resources explaining what the ViewState does. Why don't you explain your real problem? What are you trying to do, what really happens and why do you expect anything else to happen? I you just want to clear a textbox after postback, then [search and you will find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301446/clear-textbox-after-postback).

Comment: Your link does not help me !

Comment: While I do believe that my link does not directly answer your question (the answer is by the way: _"EnableViewState='true' enables the ViewState, where EnableViewState='false' disables it"_), it helps understanding what the ViewState is and what it does. **You** need to explain what your problem is, what you have tried to solve it and what did not work.

Comment: Your correct . I know that . But i don't know What happened when EnableViewState false and true ? Can you give a simple sample to me ?

Comment: Hi Ramesh.  @CodeCaster is providing clear help to you.  If you still don't understand what he is telling you, perhaps you need to do some more introductory research / reading on ASP.NET web development in general.

Answer (score 4):

Texbox Doesnt Use Viewstate here is the link to explain all [Link Explain](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2004/03/15/2273.aspx)

Comment: Okay . If i use another control . Now What happen when EnableViewState="true", and EnableViewState="false"?

Comment: it depends on control what you are using...most element like html controls doesnt support viewstate

Comment: ViewState is not required to preserve control value This is not the case, as the values are identified via posted back form field values, and assigned in the LoadPostData() method for those controls that implement IPostBackDataHandler.values see this link of msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx it explains all

Comment: When the Data assigned  in LoadPostData() ?

Comment: it is method used for loading data in controls that use ipostbackDataHandler ...i postbackDATAhANDELER  allows a server control to determine whether its state should be altered as a result of the postback, and to raise the appropriate events

Comment: you can search on msdn all is given there

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should use EnableViewState="false" on all controls on the asp.net page. The viewstate of a control is most commonly needed when you want to preserve some visual appearance of the control itself. E.g. if you change the background color of control and you want to persist that across postbacks use EnableViewState="true".

Answer (score 0):

Not all controls are affected by view state. The controls that implement IEventHandler or IDataHandler will not get affected on page postback if view state is disabled.
Textbox is one such control. If you want to see the effect in your code. Try setting the label value at run time on postback like on Click of button and check the results

Answer (score 0):

ViewState is used to persist properties of a control that are set server-side.

So, to take a contrived example, if you do something like the following in Page_Load:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    TextBox1.ForeColor = ...;
}
```

then the color you set will be preserved across postbacks in ViewState, if it is enabled.