# EnableViewState="false" does not work and Why asp.net view sate automatically decoded and stored in browser

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, state

I used asp.net text-box and set

> EnableViewState="false"

then i run my code and enter some sample texts and i enforced the post-back (which means click the button )then Textbox control retain the value .

what i am wrong in my code ?

How can i disable view-state ?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" EnableViewState="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Then i have another one doubt.

**Why asp.net view sate automatically decoded and stored in browser.** I read some articles the article says it’s a security purpose.

The user gives her/his information and he will use the particular browser and maintain the browser then why view sate is encoded. Is another reasons to decode the view state  ?

Comment: I answered the same question here please see this [link][1] hope it help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064621/i-have-one-issue-for-viewstate/16064714#16064714

Comment: @AmitSingh good . Why asp.net view sate automatically decoded and stored in browser.

Comment: check this msdn link it give all knowledge u require for view state
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms972976.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well regarding your first question this can be confusing at the beginning. Textbox are simply classes that implement the IPostBackDataHandler interface.

A nice explation can be found here-- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378180/View-State-for-TextBox-and-other-controls-that-imp

Regarding your second question about the encryption of viewstate, then you must know the user accessing the page is not only one who can view the viewstate. Pages are posted back on un encrypted channels also, so any body looking over the wire has access to it. Also the user can never be trusted.

My advice to you is to get in details about the view state on msdn. It will help you in long run.