# Disable ViewState in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to know more about ViewState. I know that ViewState is used to Persist User entered data and control values in round trips.
If I disable viewstate for complete page, then what will happened? How can then I persist the data?
for eg if I have a signup page and it has ten fields, I disable viewState of the page, then How can I persist data?

Also Do MVC use ModelBinder as alternate of ViewState or some other technique, Please tell

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have one issue for ViewState](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064621/i-have-one-issue-for-viewstate)

Comment: Can't get the explanation of the link :(

Comment: Then explain the actual problem you are having, not _"what happens if I disable the ViewState"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable the ViewState completely, then many of the asp-Controls won't persist their state. For example a Dropdown-List will 'forget' its chosen value, after a refresh of the site. You would have to handle this by yourself.

An alternative to using the ViewState might be to use session variables. But they are globally available in your application, so it might be a little harder to handle page specific information.

Comment: can you tell what MVC uses as alternate of ViewState?

Comment: I did not use MVC with ASP so far, but I believe there is no substitute, because MVC uses a strict stateless approach to a web application. Check this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381619(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

2 alternatives to `ViewState`:

1. Old fashion like, you can use the URL to pass parameters.
2. You can use session variables which also exists for each user. They can be used just like the `ViewState`, but are stored on the server: `Session["YourVariableName"] = YourVariableValue`. The value can be any object.

Comment: thanks Rob, can you tell what MVC uses as alternate of ViewState?

Comment: No sorry, I'm not familiar with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a very good explanation here,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31344/Beginner-s-Guide-To-View-State

You can disable a view state for a control as below,

```
TextBox1.EnableViewState =false;
```